# What's the use of configure_package_config_file option INSTALL_DESTINATION

Tags: cmake

For the following `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Testing)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(FooConfig.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/Goo/dmake
)

install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake
        DESTINATION lib/Foo/cmake )
```

and the `FooConfig.cmake.in` file

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

check_required_components(Foo)
```

It would finally install `FooConfig.cmake` to `lib/Foo/cmake`：

```
$ cmake ..
$ cmake --build .
$ cmake --install . --prefix ../install/
$ ls -R ../install/
../install/:
lib

../install/lib:
Foo

../install/lib/Foo:
cmake

../install/lib/Foo/cmake:
FooConfig.cmake
```

It seems that whatever value I set to the `INSTALL_DESTINATION` option of `configure_package_config_file`, it won't change `FooConfig.cmake`'s installation directory. But if I comment `INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/Goo/dmake`, CMake Error prompts

> No INSTALL_DESTINATION given to CONFIGURE_PACKAGE_CONFIG_FILE()

Then, what is the use of the `INSTALL_DESINATION` option? What its value (specifically, the above setting `lib/Goo/dmake`) actually affects?

---

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#command:configure_package_config_file):

> The `<path>` given to `INSTALL_DESTINATION` must be the destination where the `FooConfig.cmake` file will be installed to.

I know the right way is `INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/Foo/cmake`. But as I deliberately set it as `lib/Goo/dmake`, the  `FooConfig.cmake` file still rests at the desired destination `lib/Foo/cmake`. So, why this option is designed as a must?

Comment: `lib/Goo/dmake` looks like a pretty clear bug, besides the rest of your question...

Comment: @Alex Reinking: The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#command:configure_package_config_file): The `<path>` given to `INSTALL_DESTINATION` must be the destination where the `FooConfig.cmake` file will be installed to. I know the right way is `INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/Foo/cmake`. But as I deliberately set it as `lib/Goo/dmake`, the  `FooConfig.cmake` file still rests at the desired destination `lib/Foo/cmake`. So, why this option is designed as a must?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function [configure_package_config_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html#command:configure_package_config_file) **only generates** the file specified as the second argument. This function neither installs the generated file nor affects on its installation. So, its arguments can only affect on the **content** of the generated file.

If you look into the generated script `FooConfig.cmake`, then you could find the line like

```
get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)
```

This is how the script calculates installation prefix based on the path to the `FooConfig.cmake` file.

E.g. when you install the package with prefix `/usr/local` and your `FooConfig.cmake` script will be located in the directory `/usr/local/lib/Foo/cmake`, then the quoted path will be expanded into `/usr/local/lib/Foo/cmake/../../../`, which corresponds to `/usr/local/`.

Number of components `../` in the script equals to the number of components in `INSTALL_DESTINATION` parameter.

### Why 'PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR' is needed

Assume a package installs all public headers into directory `include/` (relative to installation prefix), and config script needs to deliver that directory to the user via variable `FOO_INCLUDE_DIR`.

The most direct way would be to write in the script following:

```
# FooConfig.cmake.in
...
set(FOO_INCLUDE_DIR @CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@/include)
```

so `configure_package_config_file` would substitute real install prefix instead of `@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@`.

But embedding **absolute path** into the config file prevents the package to be **relocatable**. So, once installed, the package could be used only from the installation directory, and cannot be copied elsewhere.

For relocatable package a config file computes all installation paths **relative** to the path of the config file itself, because it is the only path known to the script when it is called by `find_package`. It is like an executable can compute paths to the files located near to that executable.

If the script is installed into `lib/Foo/cmake/FooConfig.cmake`, then relative path to the include directory would be `../../../include`, so one could use following assignment in that script:

```
# FooConfig.cmake.in
...
set(FOO_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../include)
```

So, when `find_package(Foo)` will execute this script, it expands the variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) to the actual directory with the possibly relocated script.

Operating with relative paths requires much attention from the coder, so CMake allows to automate this task:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
...
# Path to the include directory in the installation tree
set(INCLUDE_DIR 'include')

configure_package_config_file(FooConfig.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/Foo/cmake
  # Tell CMake to handle variable `INCLUDE_DIR` as a path
  # under installation tree.
  PATH_VARS INCLUDE_DIR
)
```

```
# FooConfig.cmake.in
@PACKAGE_INIT@

# Here we could use `@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIR@` as reference
# to variable 'INCLUDE_DIR' set in the CMakeLists.txt.
set_and_check(FOO_INCLUDE_DIR "@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIR@")
```

If you look into the generated file, you will find that `@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIR@`
is expanded into `${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}/include`, which uses the variable `PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR`.

Comment: Great explanation on relocatability! But for `So, its arguments can only affect on the content of the generated file.`, I want to know how `INSTALL_DESTINATION` and `INSTALL_PREFIX` affect the **content**? Say, I set `INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/Goo/dmake` and `NSTALL_PREFIX /home/user/CAT`, then run `grep -nir Goo` and `grep -nir CAT` from both build tree and installation tree, it prints no relevant info. I want to find evidence that these two arguments did affect something.

Comment: "Number of components `../` in the script equals to the number of components in INSTALL_DESTINATION parameter."

Comment: My wrong, you mentioned it in your answer. Could you also explain how `INSTALL_PREFIX` affects the **content**?

Comment: Variables passed via `PATH_VARS` option may contain absolute paths. But for create a relocatable package CMake needs to transform these paths into ones **relative** to INSTALL_PREFIX. Note, that non-default setting  of `INSTALL_PREFIX` parameter has a sense only when export a **build tree** (with `export()`) command. This use case is noted in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html).

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to just say "thank you" in the comments, but this explanation is just so clear and good @Tsyvarev that I couldn't resist.  Thank you so much for such a high quality answer.

Comment: From cmake v2.23, does the usage of:

`target_sources(Foo PUBLIC FILE_SET_HEADERS BASE_DIRS 
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" FILES foo.h)`


`install(TARGETS Foo
EXPORT FooTargets
FILE_SET HEADERS DESTINATION include/
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/
RUNTIME DESTINATION bin/
)`


`install(EXPORT FooTargets
FILE FooTargets.cmake
NAMESPACE Foo::
DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo
)`


make the PATH_VARS INCLUDE_DIR useless ? or it is still required ?