# How does CMake’s configure_package_config_file() work?

Tags: c++, cmake

I was following the [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.24/guide/tutorial/Adding%20Export%20Configuration.html), and when it goes over how to export config files I was a bit confused with the output. In specific, when running the command

```
# generate the config file that is includes the exports
configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfig.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION "lib/cmake/example"
  NO_SET_AND_CHECK_MACRO
  NO_CHECK_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS_MACRO
)
```

I expect to see that `MathFunctionsConfig.cmake` is installed somewhere like `<some-directory>/lib/cmake/example/`. However, I looked into the installation directory and also `/usr/local/`, which is what `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` is, I did not find this example folder with `MathFunctionsConfig.cmake` in it. Where I did find `MathFunctionsConfig.cmake` is in `<installation-directory>/lib/cmake/MathFunctions` which is specified by the following command

```
install(FILES
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfig.cmake
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfigVersion.cmake
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/MathFunctions
)
```

So what did `configure_package_config_file` do, does it just generate `MathFunctionsConfig.cmake` and not install it? If that is the case then what does the role that `INSTALL_DESTINATION` play?

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me understand this better. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the signature you're using you get little more than `configure_file`.

The `INSTALL_DESTINATION` option comes into play to determine how to find the root of the installation directory based on the location of the configuration script. In most cases you'll use this with names of variables containing paths relative to the install root via `PATH_VARS`. This results `configure_package_config_file` which would result in cmake providing the listed variables with the `PACKAGE_` prefix for use during the configuration of the file.

**Note:** this means you should actually be passing the install destination of the configures script, i.e. `lib/cmake/MathFunctions` in your case.

### Example

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR include)

configure_package_config_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.cmake.in
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MathFunctionsConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "lib/cmake/MathFunctions" # location relative to the install root the configured file will end up in
    PATH_VARS MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR # allow us to use @PACKAGE_MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR@ to refer to <install_prefix>/include in Config.cmake.in
    NO_SET_AND_CHECK_MACRO
    NO_CHECK_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS_MACRO
)
```

**Config.cmake.in**

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "@PACKAGE_MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR@") # absolute path available here
```

**Resulting MathFunctionsConfig.cmake**

```
####### Expanded from @PACKAGE_INIT@ by configure_package_config_file() #######
####### Any changes to this file will be overwritten by the next CMake run ####
####### The input file was Config.cmake.in                            ########

get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)

####################################################################################

set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}/include") # absolute path available here
```

Comment: So from my understanding, since `INSTALL_DESTINATION` will only specify the location of the `Config.cmake` file relative to the installation root, making `INSTALL_DESTINATION` even `a/b/c` would work?

Comment: @QualsPassed: Yes, if your config file is installed into relative path containing 3 subdirectories (`lib/cmake/MathFunctions`), then any 3-components path (e.g. `a/b/c` ) will work as INSTALL_DESTINATION. But none of 2-component path (e.g. `lib/cmake`) will work. That effect is noted in the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209356/whats-the-use-of-configure-package-config-file-option-install-destination).